# How to call function "changeColor" in this case in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to call `changeColor()` in the class `ColorContainer` when `ListTile` tapped.
How to achieve this?

**Code:**

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ParentState();
  }
}

class ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  Color selectedColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (_, int i) {
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    // I want to call changeColor();
                  },
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ColorContainer(selectedColor)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  const ColorContainer(this.color);
  @override
  _ColorContainerState createState() => _ColorContainerState();
}

class _ColorContainerState extends State<ColorContainer> {
  Color color;

  void changeColor() {
    color = widget.color;
    setState(() {});
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is work for you

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (_, int i) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(i.toString()),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedColor = Colors.white;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(child: ColorContainer(selectedColor))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  const ColorContainer(this.color);
  @override
  _ColorContainerState createState() => _ColorContainerState();
}

class _ColorContainerState extends State<ColorContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Is there any way I can call the function?